# Is it possible to attach a file from firebase storage to an email using the trigger email extension?

Tags: firebase-storage, nodemailer, firebase-extensions

I added the trigger email extension to my firebase project and it works well.
I am now trying to send an email with an attachment from firebase storage.
I tried adding the access token of the file to the content field of the message and the email is sent with the corresponding file (in this case a pdf file) but when I try to open it, it is corrupted.
Am I doing something wrong or is it just not possible to attach files from storage?

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to send an attachment with this extension.

Could you provide an example of how you are adding this attachment? For example:

- A link to a file source
- Base 64 included content

A link to a file would look like

```
attachments: [
  {
    content: "invoice",
    filename: "{{invoice_link}}",
  },
],
```

Base 64 content would be similar to:

```
attachments: [
  { content: "dGhpcyBpcyBhIHRlc3Q=" // base64 string
    encoding: "base64"
    filename "ImportantDocument.pdf"
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I ended up just writing a trigger function and used nodemailer there.